# How to determine the indices of rows for which the sum of certain columns are 0?

Tags: python, numpy

How can I determine the indices of rows for which the sum of certain columns are 0?

For example, in the following array:

```
array([[ 0.9200001,  1.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ],
       [ 1.8800001,  1.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ],
       [ 2.2100001,  1.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ],
       [ 3.3400001,  1.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ],
       [ 4.3100001,  1.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ],
       [ 5.5900001,  1.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ],
       [ 6.7500001,  1.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ],
       [ 7.8300001,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ],
       [ 8.8500001,  1.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ],
       [ 9.1600001,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ],
       [10.3900001,  0.       ,  0.       ,  1.       ,  1.       ],
       [13.5600001,  0.       ,  0.       ,  1.       ,  1.       ]])
```

I'd like to get the indices of rows for which the sum of columns (1: ) is zero. In this case, it would be [7,9].

I already tried different combinations without success:

- np.nonzero(sum(operations[:,1:]==0))
- np.nonzero((operations[:,1:].sum()==0))

Sorry in advance, as I imagine this is a simple question, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Each array is a row, am I correct? Then what does "sum of columns 1" mean? Each row has only one item in column one, what do you sum?

Comment: I meant columns (1: ), as in from column 1 to end. I already edited, thanks for the notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[ 0.9200001,  1.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ],
       [ 1.8800001,  1.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ],
       [ 2.2100001,  1.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ],
       [ 3.3400001,  1.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ],
       [ 4.3100001,  1.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ],
       [ 5.5900001,  1.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ],
       [ 6.7500001,  1.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ],
       [ 7.8300001,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ],
       [ 8.8500001,  1.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ],
       [ 9.1600001,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ],
       [10.3900001,  0.       ,  0.       ,  1.       ,  1.       ],
       [13.5600001,  0.       ,  0.       ,  1.       ,  1.       ]])

# slice the array and only use the columns which shall be summed:
b = a[:,1:]
# then sum the columns by axis 1
c = b.sum(axis=1)
# then get the indices
np.where(c==0)
#out: (array([7, 9], dtype=int64),)
```

or in one line:

```
print(np.where(a[:,1:].sum(axis=1)==0))
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to sum over the columns, you need `axis=1`. If `a` is your array:

```py
np.nonzero(a[:,1:].sum(axis=1)==0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I used simple way:

```
import numpy as np
array=np.array([[ 0.9200001,  1.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ],
       [ 1.8800001,  1.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ],
       [ 2.2100001,  1.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ],
       [ 3.3400001,  1.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ],
       [ 4.3100001,  1.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ],
       [ 5.5900001,  1.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ],
       [ 6.7500001,  1.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ],
       [ 7.8300001,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ],
       [ 8.8500001,  1.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ],
       [ 9.1600001,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ,  0.       ],
       [10.3900001,  0.       ,  0.       ,  1.       ,  1.       ],
       [13.5600001,  0.       ,  0.       ,  1.       ,  1.       ]])

sumrow = np.sum(array, axis=1)
for i in range(len(array)):
    if array[i][0]==sumrow[i]:
        print(i)
```